# silver film and Super8 Films

Tags: minolta, vivitar

I recently acquired a Minolta X-700 and a Vivitar 94P Super 8 film camera but since I'm a neophyte in analog capture devices, I don't know what film I should buy in 2020 that will be kind of affordable, durable and with the best quality output for both of those two devices. I know that I should get some from Kodak but they are a bit rare and I really don't know what to get. Also a lot of photography shops are closed during these times so I can't really get help from them.

I plan to capture both color and b&w images/films with a bit of grain if possible.

If someone can light my path I would be extremely thankful.

NB: I will use the Minolta for stop motion and photos in general.

Comment: I don't understand the question. What kind of support you should buy? Are you talking about tripods?

Comment: i was more thinking about  silver pellicules and super8 films models. i'm sorry if i was not very clear, i'll reformulate a bit my question

Comment: 'pellicule' is not the correct word in English, and certainly not 'silver pellicules'. You can just say "[film](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photographic_film)" for both a _still camera_ and a _movie camera_.

Comment: What do you mean by "durable"? In what way would the film be durable?

Comment: You know that these two cameras will use totally different film, right? The Minolta uses "35mm film" (also known as 135 film), and the movie camera uses Super 8 film.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't recommend a 35mm film camera for stop motion photography. That is going to be an expensive project, considering how many frames you would need to produce an animation of even 30 seconds.

Comment: You'll find useful info in this question: [film recommendation for Mamiya 645 AFD, landscapes](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/116977)

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll take a look at the link you shared. By durable I meant capable of being stored without getting destroyed both keep them before usage and store them after being used. I might have badly formulated my question because I wanted to ask about references that suite each device, but not a film that would be used in both. I knew that they weren't using the same film type and format.

Comment: "*analog capture devices*" ? How does one capture an analog?  Film cameras  are called **film cameras**.

Comment: I meant analog in opposition to digital

Comment: @AlaskaMan One captures *via* analog - "analog" is an adjective there.  The device is analog, not digital.  It's not a common way of talking about film cameras, but they are analog capture devices, along with most video and audio cassette recorders.

Answer (score 1):

One little note, the X700 will have problems with shutter lag. It may be a while before you get it but it will happen. I remember from experience.